# HTML Signature - Embedding a website

Tags: html, embed

I'm trying to use an html email signature that pulls the html from another site. So, imagine I have the html hosted at blahblah.com/blah.html, and blah.html is:

```
<html>
<body>
Jon Jones
jon@blahblah.com
</body>
</html
```

And then my html signature would be something like `<embed src="blahblah.com/blah.html/>` that way I can manipulate the signature without having to constantly change the actual signature in Outlook (which I use to check my email).

I can't figure out any html that will do what I'm trying to do. The `embed` tag that I posted above doesn't do the trick. What simple line of html can I use to say "display what you find at blahblah.com/blah.html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would venture a guess and say this isn't the best way to do this.

From a security standpoint, I wouldn't want to be viewing any email sent by you that also brings in `somesite.com/signature.htm`. Even if it did, it would invoke a "click to view linked elements in this email" banner, and hide it until I did so (but chances are I'm not clicking).

From a recipient stand point, some spam filters block emails with externally-linked content (your intended recipient may not even get your email, or (best-case) see it with `[spam]` in the subject line.)

If you want an easy up-keep, you could place the signature in your my documents/some other folder and link to it via outlook's settings, but that about the least intense method (while also not causing concerns or issues to anyone viewing your email.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like instructions for what you want are here: http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/html-email.html

Under "How to add HTML links in Outlook HTML emails," point to blahblah.com/blah.html

On the other hand, HTML in emails is generally not a great thing because it often isn't very secure (you could send me a page with HTML that would load a virus), so many clients won't be able to recieve it or will flag it as spam.